# Google Apps re-initialize issue with Microsoft outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-workspace

Yesterday, I faced a google sync problem in outlook. Unfortunately, I had removed all data with ".PST" file. Now I am again installing GWSMO and creating a new profile using GWSMO. I have not been able to complete the process. I have tried many things like uninstalling office GWSMO. If I am given access from Google Suite Gmail, this window is not close. I have attempted to click continue, but it does not do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I noticed that you have problem with creating a new profile using GWSMO. Based on my research, I found that the following solutions to troubleshoot this issue:

[image]

For more information about it, please refer to: [Unable to create or sign in to profile](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/150403?hl=en#:%7E:text=Unable%20to%20create%20or%20sign%20in%20to%20profile).

Comment: Thank you for your support. issue has been resolved. this issue is occurred due to proxy network.